# How to remove doctype using Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to remove the doctype from a html file I am parsing but the doctype stays intact in the file.

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, null);


    List<Node>nods = doc.childNodes();
      for (Node node : nods) {

    if (node.nodeName().equals("#doctype") {

       node.remove();

  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try: node.nodeName().equals("#doctype"); ??

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but made no difference. In fact, I have verified the programs goes into the if block but it seems to ignore the remove method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Document document = ...;
document.childNodes()
    .stream()
    .filter(node -> node instanceof DocumentType)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(Node::remove);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
node.nodeName()=="#doctype"
```

Using the `==` operator to compare objects of type `String` will yield unpredictable results, when trying to compare for equality. That is because it is checking to see if both of the references point to the same object, but not have the same value. What you should use is the `equals()` method instead, which has been overridden in the String class to check for equality .

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but made no difference. In fact, I have verified the programs goes into the if block but it seems to ignore the remove method.